# Wix if and else if condition inside component element

Tags: wix, wix3.7, wix3.8

I have a .wxs file for program installation. I want to pass a part of installation depending on the IIS version (for ex. execute if IIS verion > #10  set something and else if <= #7 set something ) and continue to install other parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows Installer, components are the smallest units of installation/removal. They are entities that can be part of multiple products. For a product, only a feature can be selected for installation or removal. (When no product's installed features need a component, it is removed. When a product has no installed features, it is removed.)

A component can be in multiple features. A feature can have a condition on it. (They aren't just for user selection in a dialog.) Features can be nested.

Putting it together, it seems that you need to conditionally select features.

In WiX, you can express features, conditions and component references as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25827869/2226988) to a similar question.

You might use the WiX-provided IIS version detection in your conditions like this:

```
<PropertyRef Id="IISMAJORVERSION" /> 
<PropertyRef Id="IISMINORVERSION" />
…

<Condition Level="1"><![CDATA[IISMAJORVERSION >= "#10"]]></Condition>
```